# Gnuplot from a standard shell without entering gnuplot interactive shell

Tags: shell, gnuplot

Is it possible to run a gnuplot from a standard shell without entering the gnuplot interactive shell?

I just want to be able to type my gnuplot commands in one line from my standard shell and to be able to save standard gnuplots as aliases. Currently I have to create .sh files where I write my commands which is quite terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean

```
echo "plot sin(x)" | gnuplot -p
```

OR

```
echo -e "set term png\n set output 'alma.png'\n plot sin(x)\n" | gnuplot
```

?

OR

```
echo | gnuplot -p -e "plot sin(x)"
```

(last one by Christoph)

Comment: No need to use `echo`:  `gnuplot -p -e "plot sin(x)"`

Comment: @Christoph You are right. But you mean `echo | gnuplot -p -e "plot sin(x)"` don't you?

Comment: Great! Exactly what I needed.